# Python script failing to correctly encode special Unicode characters

Tags: python, unicode, character-encoding, special-characters, python-unicode

I am converting a text file (`words.txt`) that is basically a dictionary in this format:

`good morning, Góðan daginn`

into a json file (`converted.json`) in this format

```
{
    "wordId": 1,
    "word": "good morning",
    "translation": "Góðan daginn"
}
```

The conversion from a text file to a json file works totally fine and as expected but the characters encoding are kind of messed up and here's how:

for encoding this character **`ð`** instead of doing this **`\u00f0`** the script encode that character like this: **`\u00c3\u00b0`**

**Question:** How to fix and/or adjust the script so it can correctly encode those special characters? keeping in mind that those characters are mainly Icelandic/Scandinavian and I am using **PyCharm** as an **IDE**.

**PS** Please take into consideration that my Python skills are a bit limited!!

This is the script **converter.py**:

```
import json

with open('words.txt', 'r') as f_in, \
    open('converted.json', 'w') as f_out:
cnt = 1
data = []
for line in f_in:
    line = line.split(',')
    if len(line) != 2:
        continue
    d = {"wordId": cnt, "word": line[0].strip(), "translation": line[1].strip()}
    data.append(d)
    cnt += 1

f_out.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

**I am using Python 3**

Comment: If this is Python 2, you need to decode the strings from your file using `.decode('utf-8')`, because otherwise you're getting the raw byte strings. (Python 3 prevents you from making this mistake - strongly recommend upgrading to Python 3 for any new code!)

Comment: @nneonneo I just tried with Python 3 and Jupyter and I still get the same wrong result! anything else I can do?

Comment: Python as default use `UTF-8` and `ð` in utf-8 has code `\u00c3\u00b0`. It has code `\u00f0` in `Latin-1` See `print( 'ð'.encode('latin-1') )`

Comment: @furas I tried this `"translation": line[1].strip().encode('latin-1')` but I got the following error : `UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u201c' in position 2: ordinal not in range(256)`

Comment: maybe you need different encoding - ie. `latin2`, `cp1250`, `cp1251`, `cp1252`, etc., `iso8859-2`, etc. - some chars may have the same code in different encoding. See table [Standard Encodings](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings)

Comment: `print( 'ð\u201c'.encode('cp1252') )` gives `b'\xf0\x93'`

Comment: BTW: `mac_iceland` also works but gives different codes `print('ð\u201c'.encode('mac_iceland'))`

Comment: @furas the generated json file will be used in a `.Dart` application so it is best if I stick latin-1

Comment: I don't use `Dart` but I would surprised if it would need `utf-8` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem is that `json.dumps`, you may need to use `ensure_ascii=False`. Like:

```
f_out.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False))
```

So basically, as the document says:

> If ensure_ascii is true (the default), the output is guaranteed to
>   have all incoming non-ASCII characters escaped. If ensure_ascii is
>   false, these characters will be output as-is.